# Fluid/Auto-align List of blocks/boxes using css/javascript

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i made a list of blocks using bootstrap 3.0. but im having problems with the desired outcome. Please help, thanks.

**Current outcome**
[image: CURRENT OUTCOME]
**Desired outcome**
[image]

**Custom style from current outcome**

```
 .list_comments{
    list-style: none; 
    margin-left:-40px;
    }
    .list-comment-block{
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:-15px;
    }
```

**Markup**

```
<ul class="list-comments"> 
                          <li class="list-comment-block">
                            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                              <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-2x pull-right text-success"></i><h4>A student said</h4>
                               <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x  pull-left fa-border"></i>
                                <p>Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.</p>

                               </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>

                         <li class="list-comment-block">
                           <div class="thumbnail"> 
                              <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-2x pull-right text-success"></i><h4>A student said</h4>
                               <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x  pull-left fa-border"></i>
                                <p>Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.</p>

                               </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>

                         <li class="list-comment-block">
                            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                              <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-2x pull-right text-success"></i><h4>A student said</h4>
                               <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x  pull-left fa-border"></i>
                                <p>Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.</p>

                               </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>

                          <li class="list-comment-block">
                            <div class="thumbnail"> 
                              <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-comment fa-2x pull-right text-success"></i><h4>A student said</h4>
                               <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x  pull-left fa-border"></i>
                                <p>Use a few styles together and you'll have easy pull quotes or
                                 a great introductory article icon.</p>

                               </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>



                        </ul>
```

I have tried using position:relative, inherit too. I appreciate any answers

Comment: Just to head you in the right direction, what you want is a masonry script. There's a couple out there and Google will help you find them. [Here's one](http://masonry.desandro.com/), and there's even a [jQuery plugin](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/).

Comment: That's just what i need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to get the layout you want using DIV container elements instead of a UL. Then you can use CSS3 `column-width` to evenly align the thumbnails in a "masonry" style layout..

```
.list-comments {
 -moz-column-width: 25em;
 -webkit-column-width: 25em;
 -moz-column-gap: .5em;
 -webkit-column-gap: .5em; 
}

.thumbnail {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:  .5em;
 padding:  0; 
 width:98%;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/129218